# Jquery way to push an element to the top of the z-index order?

Tags: jquery

What are the ways of finding the highest CSS z-index value of specified set of elements and pushing one element that is clicked to the top of the z-index order.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using something simple like this:

```
var elements = $('selector').click(function(){ $(this).css('z-index', max++); }), 
    max = Math.max.apply(Math, elements.map(function() { 
        return parseInt($(this).css('z-index'), 10) || 0; 
    }).get());
```

This will cause each clicked element in the set to gain a `z-index` one higher than the current one.

**Edit:** New method of calculating maximum `z-index` using `Math.max` courtesy of AndyE in the chatroom: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/96656#96656

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/876332.aspx) plug-in.

Comment: funky (+1). but it would be nicer if you provided sample code in your answer.

Comment: there are some resources at the end of the post